# This is a pathauto bug?

Tags: path-aliases

I use the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module to redirct my **user/nid**  to **/username** ,
I set all of it's setting with my disired option,
but have a exception in it, 
all of this name

```
blah.blah
d.dddd
df33.dddd
fafdd.dd
```

But when I start it with a.s???? it's don't work and I can't handle this, and don't register it. Do you know any thing about this pattern a.s in pathauto?